# Angular8 - Downloading Excel .xlsx saves base64 string in file

Tags: javascript, angular8, filesaver.js

I've studied all of the SO Similar Questions about this problem, a few were helpful, but did not directly address the saving of an xlsx file to the local Win10 downloads folder.

The xlsx file sits on a CentOS 7 server. If I use Filezilla to copy it to Win10, it's fine.

Looking at the component code below, I am reading the xlsx from the server and getting its base64Str, which matches exactly what I used to store the file. I create a blob fine, but [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), saves the Win10 file with its contents as the base64Str, instead of a an xlsx binary. Can FileSaver save binary content, or only text?

Thanks for helping!

**Component Code**

```
//INPUT DATA: docName: test.xlsx; mediaType: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; snippet base64Str: VUVzREJCUU...FBQUFBPQ=
//NOTE: input data is from a CentOS 7 filesystem 

const byteStr = atob(base64Str);
const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteStr.length);
const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
for (let i = 0; i < byteStr.length; i++) {
  int8Array[i] = byteStr.charCodeAt(i);
}
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: mediaType }); //also tried type: 'application/octet-stream'   

//alternate technique that produces same corrupted result  
//const base64Response = await fetch(`data:` +mediaType +`;base64,${base64Str}`);
//const blob = await base64Response.blob();

fileSaver.saveAs(blob, docName);  //saves to Win10 downloads folder
```

Comment: what is your expectation ? do you want to save the file(xls) coming from the server in base64 string format ?

Comment: My expectation is that I can take the base64Str that I have, and save it to my Win10 downloads folder as a double-clickable Excel XLSX file, that the Excel app on my Win10 computer can open. And it looks identical to the XLSX file that I started with. The question is, does FileSaver allow saving files like this, or maybe there is a different way to save it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver  please check this npm module

Comment: Thanks @ShivanshSeth, I will first try your code for saveAsXlsxFile() below. If that fails I will study ngx-filesaver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try The below code. (Here in this example I have demonstrate the following 1) Input base64 string to a input text area 2) on click of download file link 3) will prompt to download the file into correct xlsx format without corrupted data).

Kindly modify the code as per your need . Example only demonstrate the file download feature.

Point to notice :

```
var mediaType="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,";
```

```js
 function saveAsXlsxFile(){
      var mediaType="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,";
      var userInp = document.getElementById('base64input');
     // var userInp = "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";
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = mediaType+userInp.value;
      //a.href = mediaType+userInp;
      a.download = 'filename.xlsx';
      a.textContent = 'Download file!';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="paste the base64 data here, exclude readable headers" id='base64input' type="textarea"></textarea>
<br>
<input onclick="saveAsXlsxFile()" type="button" value="update content of link"></button>
```

HTML code for demo only ( not mandatory for your requirement)

```
<textarea placeholder="paste the base64 data here, exclude readable headers" id='base64input'></textarea>
<br>
<input onclick="saveAsXlsxFile()" type="button" value="update content of link"></button>


Sample userInp value Try this :
```

> UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBBN4LPbgEAAAQFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACsVMluwjAQvVfqP0S+Vomhh6qqCBy6HFsk6AeYeJJYJLblGSj8fSdmUVWxCMElUWzPWybzPBit2iZZQkDjbC76WU8kYAunja1y8T39SJ9FgqSsVo2zkIs1oBgN7+8G07UHTLjaYi5qIv8iJRY1tAoz58HyTulCq4g/QyW9KuaqAvnY6z3JwlkCSyl1GGI4eINSLRpK3le8vFEyM1Ykr5tzHVUulPeNKRSxULm0+h9J6srSFKBdsWgZOkMfQGmsAahtMh8MM4YJELExFPIgZ4AGLyPdusq4MgrD2nh8YOtHGLqd4662dV/8O4LRkIxVoE/Vsne5auSPC/OZc/PsNMilrYktylpl7E73Cf54GGV89W8spPMXgc/oIJ4xkPF5vYQIc4YQad0A3rrtEfQcc60C6Anx9FY3F/AX+5QOjtQ4OI+c2gCXd2EXka469QwEgQzsQ3Jo2PaMHPmr2w7dnaJBH+CW8Q4b/gIAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhALVVMCP0AAAATAIAAAsACAJfcmVscy8ucmVscyCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACskk1PwzAMhu9I/IfI99XdkBBCS3dBSLshVH6ASdwPtY2jJBvdvyccEFQagwNHf71+/Mrb3TyN6sgh9uI0rIsSFDsjtnethpf6cXUHKiZylkZxrOHEEXbV9dX2mUdKeSh2vY8qq7iooUvJ3yNG0/FEsRDPLlcaCROlHIYWPZmBWsZNWd5i+K4B1UJT7a2GsLc3oOqTz5t/15am6Q0/iDlM7NKZFchzYmfZrnzIbCH1+RpVU2g5abBinnI6InlfZGzA80SbvxP9fC1OnMhSIjQS+DLPR8cloPV/WrQ08cudecQ3CcOryPDJgosfqN4BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBFujwYXQMAAFoIAAAPAAAAeGwvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1srFXvb5s8EP7+SvsfEN8pxgECqHQqBPRWaqeqzdovlSYXTLEKOLNNk6ra/74zhPTXNGXdosTGvuPxc77nLoefN21jPFAhGe9i0zlApkG7gpesu4vNr8vcCkxDKtKVpOEdjc1HKs3PR5/+O1xzcX/L+b0BAJ2MzVqpVWTbsqhpS+QBX9EOLBUXLVGwFHe2XAlKSllTqtrGxgj5dktYZ44IkdgHg1cVK+iCF31LOzWCCNoQBfRlzVZyQmuLfeBaIu77lVXwdgUQt6xh6nEANY22iE7uOi7IbQNhbxzP2Aj4+vBzEAx4OglM745qWSG45JU6AGh7JP0ufgfZjvPqCjbv72A/JNcW9IHpHO5YCf+DrPwdlv8M5qC/RnNAWoNWIri8D6J5O27YPDqsWEOvRukaZLX6QlqdqcY0GiJVVjJFy9icw5Kv6asN0a+SnjVgxTMfB6Z9tJPzuTBKWpG+UUsQ8gQPleH7Ifa0JwjjuFFUdETRlHcKdLiN6281N2CnNQeFGxf0e88EhcICfUGsMJIiIrfynKja6EUTm2l081VC+DeSqlreTEUhb14ok7wvgz/QJil0wDZEPLIan99GD+RENOnvXAkDnk8Wp5CDS/IAGYG8l9uCPYErD749hYEfJug4tAK88CwX48AKk3loeW6a+OnxDOez+Q+IQvhRwUmv6m2WNWZsulqXb01nZDNZHBT1rHw+/wltP5ae3wyT7YeOVPezK0bX8lkPemlsrllX8nVsWo5W8ePr5XowXrNS1aCT0MXgMu79T9ldDYwdNGyC7jWz2HxCWT6fp1lqBUE+s9xFkFthnodWFqYo8HGKMcIDI/sFpaFzArVhNrpB7Ze6mzrQovWsbxeeRaTPECelM2Rveq0gTQHq1tPgGDoIh9qDbtSpVMMMwmJAz3HR8RyFroWyGeQnCLEVuDNspe4CZ948W2SJp/OjO3/0L/rfoO9o+kvRLGsi1FKQ4h7+iC5olRAJShoDAr4vySZekKAZUHRzJ7dcJ0RWkviu5S3ymTd3Fmnm5c9kdfjVB7tPYA9vU6J6qExdlMM60mO+3d1tVuPGNk+vii66WOh73779O8dLiL6hezrnV3s6pl/Olmd7+p5my2/X+SCkX0ZrD9nQ46Ahe8rh0U8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCBPpSX8wAAALoCAAAaAAgBeGwvX3JlbHMvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sLnJlbHMgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACsUk1LxDAQvQv+hzB3m3YVEdl0LyLsVesPCMm0KdsmITN+9N8bKrpdWNZLLwNvhnnvzcd29zUO4gMT9cErqIoSBHoTbO87BW/N880DCGLtrR6CRwUTEuzq66vtCw6acxO5PpLILJ4UOOb4KCUZh6OmIkT0udKGNGrOMHUyanPQHcpNWd7LtOSA+oRT7K2CtLe3IJopZuX/uUPb9gafgnkf0fMZCUk8DXkA0ejUISv4wUX2CPK8/GZNec5rwaP6DOUcq0seqjU9fIZ0IIfIRx9/KZJz5aKZu1Xv4XRC+8opv9vyLMv072bkycfV3wAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAAdhSeKLAgAARAYAABgAAAB4bC93b3Jrc2hlZXRzL3NoZWV0MS54bWyclV9v2jAUxd8n7TtYfof8IUCJklSFCK0Pk6Z127txbsBqEnu2gXbTvvuuk5GmsE2oEiA7Pv7d4/jYJLdPdUUOoI2QTUqDsU8JNFwWotmm9OuX9eiGEmNZU7BKNpDSZzD0Nnv/LjlK/Wh2AJYgoTEp3VmrYs8zfAc1M2OpoMGRUuqaWezqrWeUBla0k+rKC31/5tVMNLQjxPoahixLwSGXfF9DYzuIhopZ9G92QpkTrebX4GqmH/dqxGWtELERlbDPLZSSmsf320Zqtqlw3U9BxDh50vgJ8Ts5lWmfX1SqBdfSyNKOkex1ni+Xv/AWHuM96XL9V2GCyNNwEG4DX1Dh2ywF054VvsAmb4TNeph7XTreiyKlP+d3q/wmDxajSeQvR1EeYcZmK3/kr6eL+XI5W4fL8BfNkkLgDrtVEQ1lSu+COJ9QL0va/HwTcDSDNrFs8wAVcAtYI6DExXMj5aMT3uMjH4mmFTgi41YcYAVVldL1FBP+va2BTSzg9RWG7VO1dRvoT5oUULJ9ZT/L4wcQ253FstEYWW0i4uI5B8Mxolh6PGm5LTZnlmWJlkeC240+jWLu8ARx9K+ZWcKd9s6J2ymINLiaQzZPvANa5H8Uy0uF/1qxulQErxX5pSLsFR7a7r1jPq737sQpxd/e++TM+3AsOnM9HJue+R2Ozf7uFMN3vVMn/r9TVPSruDlzOhxbnDkdjgUvG9O91C5zXTgU28JHpreiMaSCsk3QnBLdhcwfY9tK5XI1x7htpLWyPvV2eMECpgUzR0kppT11MNeO+wB2r4hiCvSD+IH32oISqQXmtL1BU6qktpoJS92fghWcVbkS7vgQHbvjq++LoD0k/f2f/QYAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAMEXEL5OBwAAxiAAABMAAAB4bC90aGVtZS90aGVtZTEueG1s7FnNixs3FL8X+j8Mc3f8NeOPJd7gz2yT3SRknZQctbbsUVYzMpK8GxMCJTn1UiikpZdCbz2U0kADDb30jwkktOkf0SfN2COt5SSbbEpadg2LR/69p6f3nn5683Tx0r2YekeYC8KSll++UPI9nIzYmCTTln9rOCg0fE9IlIwRZQlu+Qss/Evbn35yEW3JCMfYA/lEbKGWH0k52yoWxQiGkbjAZjiB3yaMx0jCI58Wxxwdg96YFiulUq0YI5L4XoJiUHt9MiEj7A2VSn97qbxP4TGRQg2MKN9XqrElobHjw7JCiIXoUu4dIdryYZ4xOx7ie9L3KBISfmj5Jf3nF7cvFtFWJkTlBllDbqD/MrlMYHxY0XPy6cFq0iAIg1p7pV8DqFzH9ev9Wr+20qcBaDSClaa22DrrlW6QYQ1Q+tWhu1fvVcsW3tBfXbO5HaqPhdegVH+whh8MuuBFC69BKT5cw4edZqdn69egFF9bw9dL7V5Qt/RrUERJcriGLoW1ane52hVkwuiOE94Mg0G9kinPUZANq+xSU0xYIjflWozuMj4AgAJSJEniycUMT9AIsriLKDngxNsl0wgSb4YSJmC4VCkNSlX4rz6B/qYjirYwMqSVXWCJWBtS9nhixMlMtvwroNU3IC+ePXv+8Onzh789f/To+cNfsrm1KktuByVTU+7Vj1///f0X3l+//vDq8Tfp1CfxwsS//PnLl7//8Tr1sOLcFS++ffLy6ZMX333150+PHdrbHB2Y8CGJsfCu4WPvJothgQ778QE/ncQwQsSSQBHodqjuy8gCXlsg6sJ1sO3C2xxYxgW8PL9r2bof8bkkjpmvRrEF3GOMdhh3OuCqmsvw8HCeTN2T87mJu4nQkWvuLkqsAPfnM6BX4lLZjbBl5g2KEommOMHSU7+xQ4wdq7tDiOXXPTLiTLCJ9O4Qr4OI0yVDcmAlUi60Q2KIy8JlIITa8s3eba/DqGvVPXxkI2FbIOowfoip5cbLaC5R7FI5RDE1Hb6LZOQycn/BRyauLyREeoop8/pjLIRL5jqH9RpBvwoM4w77Hl3ENpJLcujSuYsYM5E9dtiNUDxz2kySyMR+Jg4hRZF3g0kXfI/ZO0Q9QxxQsjHctwm2wv1mIrgF5GqalCeI+mXOHbG8jJm9Hxd0grCLZdo8tti1zYkzOzrzqZXauxhTdIzGGHu3PnNY0GEzy+e50VciYJUd7EqsK8jOVfWcYAFlkqpr1ilylwgrZffxlG2wZ29xgngWKIkR36T5GkTdSl045ZxUep2ODk3gNQLlH+SL0ynXBegwkru/SeuNCFlnl3oW7nxdcCt+b7PHYF/ePe2+BBl8ahkg9rf2zRBRa4I8YYYICgwX3YKIFf5cRJ2rWmzulJvYmzYPAxRGVr0Tk+SNxc+Jsif8d8oedwFzBgWPW/H7lDqbKGXnRIGzCfcfLGt6aJ7cwHCSrHPWeVVzXtX4//uqZtNePq9lzmuZ81rG9fb1QWqZvHyByibv8uieT7yx5TMhlO7LBcW7Qnd9BLzRjAcwqNtRuie5agHOIviaNZgs3JQjLeNxJj8nMtqP0AxaQ2XdwJyKTPVUeDMmoGOkh3UrFZ/QrftO83iPjdNOZ7msupqpCwWS+XgpXI1Dl0qm6Fo9796t1Ot+6FR3WZcGKNnTGGFMZhtRdRhRXw5CFF5nhF7ZmVjRdFjRUOqXoVpGceUKMG0VFXjl9uBFveWHQdpBhmYclOdjFae0mbyMrgrOmUZ6kzOpmQFQYi8zII90U9m6cXlqdWmqvUWkLSOMdLONMNIwghfhLDvNlvtZxrqZh9QyT7liuRtyM+qNDxFrRSInuIEmJlPQxDtu+bVqCLcqIzRr+RPoGMPXeAa5I9RbF6JTuHYZSZ5u+HdhlhkXsodElDpck07KBjGRmHuUxC1fLX+VDTTRHKJtK1eAED5a45pAKx+bcRB0O8h4MsEjaYbdGFGeTh+B4VOucP6qxd8drCTZHMK9H42PvQM65zcRpFhYLysHjomAi4Ny6s0xgZuwFZHl+XfiYMpo17yK0jmUjiM6i1B2ophknsI1ia7M0U8rHxhP2ZrBoesuPJiqA/a9T903H9XKcwZp5memxSrq1HST6Yc75A2r8kPUsiqlbv1OLXKuay65DhLVeUq84dR9iwPBMC2fzDJNWbxOw4qzs1HbtDMsCAxP1Db4bXVGOD3xric/yJ3MWnVALOtKnfj6yty81WYHd4E8enB/OKdS6FBCb5cjKPrSG8iUNmCL3JNZjQjfvDknLf9+KWwH3UrYLZQaYb8QVINSoRG2q4V2GFbL/bBc6nUqD+BgkVFcDtPr+gFcYdBFdmmvx9cu7uPlLc2FEYuLTF/MF7Xh+uK+XNl8ce8RIJ37tcqgWW12aoVmtT0oBL1Oo9Ds1jqFXq1b7w163bDRHDzwvSMNDtrVblDrNwq1crdbCGolZX6jWagHlUo7qLcb/aD9ICtjYOUpfWS+APdqu7b/AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAIFJ/Xf0CAADCBwAADQAAAHhsL3N0eWxlcy54bWy0VW1v0zAQ/o7Ef7D8PctLm9JWSSbaLtIkQEgbEl+dxGmt+SVy3JGC+O+cnbTN2IAxRL/EPp+fe+6e8zW57ARH91S3TMkUhxcBRlSWqmJym+JPt7k3x6g1RFaEK0lTfKAtvsxev0pac+D0ZkepQQAh2xTvjGmWvt+WOypIe6EaKuGkVloQA1u99dtGU1K19pLgfhQEM18QJnGPsBTlc0AE0Xf7xiuVaIhhBePMHBwWRqJcXm+l0qTgQLULp6REXTjTEer0MYizPoojWKlVq2pzAbi+qmtW0sd0F/7CJ+UZCZBfhhTGfhA9yL3TL0Sa+preMysfzpJaSdOiUu2lSXEERG0JlndSfZG5PQKFB68sab+ie8LBEmI/S0rFlUYGpIPKOYskgvYea8JZoZl1q4lg/NCbI2twag9+gkHtrdG3PHo2WVJYr/8ey4VsISbj/FSBiU0WDFkCrWKoljls0LC+PTSQqoSu7ik7vz94bzU5hFH8/Aut4qyyLLZrV2C9LVKcu18QWJhiOGCyoh2tUjybOvQRYVtPR859IMdC6Qpe7FFnK2lvyhJOawOomm139mtUY2MoY6Crs6RiZKsk4Vai441hAbAl5fzGvurP9QPsrkZyL3JhroEezAcr7nEJvIZlj9dvLP4YrccewVph/h4WdfUJ/xm3of/HpE63EWkafrCtMHT6r7BCyPXpBH/GgooMWC5vyHRUzgfFPJUF2feV4g92PHJ4qUNqqNgzbph8opCAWXVnaVz7GDvqnGinKKBQRWuy5+b2dJji8/o9rdheQHEGr4/sXhkHkeLz+p3toHBme5F25l0Lzxm+aK9Zir9drd4sNld55M2D1dybTmjsLeLVxoun69Vmky+CKFh/Hw3cfxi37v8BmiWcLlsOQ1kPyQ7kb862FI82PX33koD2mPsimgVv4zDw8kkQetMZmXvz2ST28jiMNrPp6irO4xH3+IVjOfDDsB/wlny8NExQzuRRq6NCYyuIBNvfJOEflfDPf77ZDwAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAMP/6oXRAAAAjwEAABQAAAB4bC9zaGFyZWRTdHJpbmdzLnhtbHTQwWrDMAwG4Ptg72C0c+skgzGG48IKPe6wdQ/gJVptiOU0UsL29nNgh+JuR31Cv4TM7isOasGJQ6IW6m0FCqlLfaBTC+/Hw+YRFIuj3g2JsIVvZNjZ2xvDLCrPErfgRcYnrbnzGB1v04iUO59pik5yOZ00jxO6nj2ixEE3VfWgowsEqkszSd7bgJopnGfc/0IN1nCwRuwxyICb2mixRq90yc3ffF/yi4tY2psPiyP2pb+6JZT2nD72pd39F3h165p4hWvkBer8UPsDAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA7bTJLwQAAAEIBAAAjAAAAeGwvd29ya3NoZWV0cy9fcmVscy9zaGVldDEueG1sLnJlbHOEj8GKwjAURfcD/kN4e5PWhQxDUzciuFXnA2L62gbbl5D3FP17sxxlwOXlcM/lNpv7PKkbZg6RLNS6AoXkYxdosPB72i2/QbE46twUCS08kGHTLr6aA05OSonHkFgVC7GFUST9GMN+xNmxjgmpkD7m2UmJeTDJ+Ysb0Kyqam3yXwe0L0617yzkfVeDOj1SWf7sjn0fPG6jv85I8s+ESTmQYD6iSDnIRe3ygGJB63f2nmt9DgSmbczL8/YJAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCj1j1wNgEAAOQCAAAnAAAAeGwvcHJpbnRlclNldHRpbmdzL3ByaW50ZXJTZXR0aW5nczEuYmluzJK7SgNREIa/ObthN4YQ0cY7C6YSA4ksYmETYsBAIsFFSJHCItha28XK2k5S+AA+hLUPYBmwFfEBLJ3ZrJigpLDyDP/M7NyY85/t06fFCRU6nCkqJDQ5pUpNMwnH1PWrS6S5nmZrHCiqWhuRHh8ZE7rSyzAQ8owKcThACOg5Udtznuo68aT6z3rll07RmFOIOYYfx79KGked0N0EZc19KHa17k2RJNWmlc+/YZcGbfbnba33f2ZR/tP9YzZaxW2jRrm3w90S3K/BQGUnk8EMaY8swDXR+DbjU41xax15tflUT0jOqcmJkwBDyv4MQ3E4Klif/QXtEB6KcL4MF+vwrvZpdfJcYhPU9bLu0iU5HefEt4BzTvb4li0OdcdXr+wL3tRrm7uZTvgKDnW76YU+AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAVJMQakMBAABrAgAAEQAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2NvcmUueG1sIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAjJJfS8MwFMXfBb9DyXubtnNDQtuByp4cCJsovoXkbg02f0jiun1703bW6nzwMTnn/nLOJcXyKJvoANYJrUqUJSmKQDHNhdqX6Hm7im9R5DxVnDZaQYlO4NCyur4qmCFMW3iy2oD1AlwUSMoRZkpUe28Ixo7VIKlLgkMFcaetpD4c7R4byt7pHnCepgsswVNOPcUdMDYjEZ2RnI1I82GbHsAZhgYkKO9wlmT42+vBSvfnQK9MnFL4kwmdznGnbM4GcXQfnRiNbdsm7ayPEfJn+HX9uOmrxkJ1u2KAqoIzwixQr221qcWBKldHG/B1gSdKt8WGOr8OC98J4Hen3+ZLQyD3RQY88ChEI0ORL+Vldv+wXaEqT/MsTvM4v9mmC5LlZDZ/697/Md9FHS7kOcX/iXOSTYlfgKrAF9+j+gQAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAGFJCRCJAQAAEQMAABAACAFkb2NQcm9wcy9hcHAueG1sIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAnJJBb9swDIXvA/ofDN0bOd1QDIGsYkhX9LBhAZK2Z02mY6GyJIiskezXj7bR1Nl66o3ke3j6REndHDpf9JDRxVCJ5aIUBQQbaxf2lXjY3V1+FQWSCbXxMUAljoDiRl98UpscE2RygAVHBKxES5RWUqJtoTO4YDmw0sTcGeI272VsGmfhNtqXDgLJq7K8lnAgCDXUl+kUKKbEVU8fDa2jHfjwcXdMDKzVt5S8s4b4lvqnszlibKj4frDglZyLium2YF+yo6MulZy3amuNhzUH68Z4BCXfBuoezLC0jXEZtepp1YOlmAt0f3htV6L4bRAGnEr0JjsTiLEG29SMtU9IWT/F/IwtAKGSbJiGYzn3zmv3RS9HAxfnxiFgAmHhHHHnyAP+ajYm0zvEyznxyDDxTjjbgW86c843XplP+id7HbtkwpGFU/XDhWd8SLt4awhe13k+VNvWZKj5BU7rPg3UPW8y+yFk3Zqwh/rV878wPP7j9MP18npRfi75XWczJd/+sv4LAAD//wMAUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAEE3gs9uAQAABAUAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAtVUwI/QAAABMAgAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACnAwAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEARbo8GF0DAABaCAAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADMBgAAeGwvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAIE+lJfzAAAAugIAABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVgoAAHhsL19yZWxzL3dvcmtib29rLnhtbC5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAAdhSeKLAgAARAYAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiQwAAHhsL3dvcmtzaGVldHMvc2hlZXQxLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDBFxC+TgcAAMYgAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEoPAAB4bC90aGVtZS90aGVtZTEueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhACBSf139AgAAwgcAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyRYAAHhsL3N0eWxlcy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAw//qhdEAAACPAQAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADxGQAAeGwvc2hhcmVkU3RyaW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAO20yS8EAAABCAQAAIwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0GgAAeGwvd29ya3NoZWV0cy9fcmVscy9zaGVldDEueG1sLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAo9Y9cDYBAADkAgAAJwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD2GwAAeGwvcHJpbnRlclNldHRpbmdzL3ByaW50ZXJTZXR0aW5nczEuYmluUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAFSTEGpDAQAAawIAABEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcR0AAGRvY1Byb3BzL2NvcmUueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAGFJCRCJAQAAEQMAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA6x8AAGRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAwADAAmAwAAqiIAAAAA

[image: Sample Image screen]

Happy to help further if needed. :)

Comment: Hi @Shivansh, I found that answer on SO 58335807 earlier, I could not get it working. You did add much detail, Thanks. I will revisit.

Comment: Hi @Shivansh, I tried your suggestion, and modified it for my app like this: `    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = taValue;
    a.download = "test.xlsx";
    a.click();
` It did download, but the resulting XLSX file is still the base64 string. Same as all other tries.

Comment: Then problem seems to be with your base64  converted string . Can you please check the same and if possible please share

Comment: I have updated my answer with the sample hard coded base64 string . Uncomment the line & use the sample string & see it its working for you or not .

Comment: Hi @Shivansh, Thanks for the very thorough code and test case. Your code works fine.

Comment: Good to know. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

so I used this. Might also work for anyone trying to convert a static base 64 string to xlxs file. This solutions assumes that you know the file type.

```
let toConvert = 'UEsDBBQAAAgIABSJA..'//supply your full plain string here
let  file = `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,${toConvert}`;
setTimeout(() => {
  fileSaver.saveAs(file, 'fileName');
}, 1300);//timeout is only added to simulate time to load. you can take it out
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works , but try setting the mediaType like below :

```
const mediaType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
```

Comment: I tried both blob techniques with your suggestion, both generate an xlsx file that when opened with TextPad only contains the base64Str. I've been saying "corrupted", but not true.

Comment: I just realised that you might be passing the wrong input for blob conversion.
I think you need to pass int8Array as the input.
const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: mediaType });

Comment: I tried that int8Array, again, using hard-coded type w/wo ;charset=UTF-8. xlsx contents are same base64Str.

Comment: I've re-written my question because creating the blob seems to be working. I've tried four blob techniques, all end up producing the same blob when viewed in the browser debugger. But, I think FileSaver is the problem. I'm still hoping for a solution.